# How to setAttribute multiple elements in HTML using array?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide multiple section in my HTML document based on button click, except for one. However, I got an error as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: arr[i].setAttribute is not a function
```

My code snippet look like below;

```
const hideOthers = (keepSec) => {
  let allSec = ["1Sec", "2Sec", "3Sec", "4Sec", "5Sec", "6Sec", "7Sec"];
  arr = allSec.filter((e) => e !== keepSec);
  console.log(arr);
  // arr.forEach(element => {
  //    element.setAttribute("hidden", true);
  // });
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].setAttribute("hidden", true);
  }
};
```

Before, I tried using the long way and it works fine. It was by putting multiple lines of setAttribute like below:

```
1Sec.setAttribute("hidden", true);
2Sec.setAttribute("hidden", true);
3Sec.setAttribute("hidden", true);
```

How do I minimize the coding and perhaps run the function based on the data provided by the array? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `arr` contains strings, not elements, strings don't have attributes. Also, a variable name can't start with a number, you should see an error message in the console.

Comment: The code does not seem to be selecting any HTML elements?

Comment: Side note: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) on my anemic old blog. You need to declare `arr`.

Comment: *"Before, I tried using the long way and it works fine. It was by putting multiple lines of setAttribute like below"* The code below that won't parse. You can't have identifiers that start with digits.

Comment: Assuming you've used those variable names in the question only, and your real code works, the question is, how have you actually assigned a value to the variables? To create a bunch of variables based on DOM queries like `getElementById`, and then assign the variables into an array is almost an anti-pattern. Identify the elements to hide with a class, then collect them by using `querySelectorAll` and iterate that array, and set the attributes in the loop (or just add a class which hides the element).

Comment: yes I did change the variable names. sorry for the confusions. I did assign the sec variable to the  document.getElementById("");. Thanks for the guides and I'll update my code accordingly.

Comment: You haven't explained the use-case, but it looks like you have a SPA app where you want to show a single section at the time, and the button is a Next button, or sth. near to similar. If that's the case, you should take a totally different approach. `id`s are not practical to use on dynamic pages, `id`s are easily conflicting and a nightmare to maintain when the app grows. Instead, create a robust DOM structure, and [keep book of the visible element in a JS variable](https://jsfiddle.net/t2wjqd57/). That way you can add new sections or remove olds without needing to update the JS part at all.

Comment: thanks for the workflow demo @teemu. However, I'm thinking of a design such as a custom tab, where all the buttons are visible and clicking one of them will hide all the other section except for the clicked one. What is your suggestions on this?

Comment: OK, if you need a tabbing system, you could do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/dtn5ezsr/1/). All the DOM queries are done only once, and never in the event handler (DOM queries are time consuming). With this simple function you can create multiple tabbing systems on the page if needed (ex. for the pop-up dialogs). For a full-fledged tabbing system I'd recommend OOP, you would have better control over the tabs and it would also reduce the memory consumption a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Sec1 = document.querySelector('.Sec1');
const Sec2 = document.querySelector('.Sec2');

const hideOthers = (keepSec) =>{
    let allSec = [{name: 'Sec1', obj: Sec1 }, {name: 'Sec2', obj: Sec2}];
    
    arr = allSec.filter(e => e.name !== keepSec);
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].obj.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    }
}
hideOthers();
```

same other comment above,  your array is a string[], not DOM object, so u can't setAttribute()
My solution is I use array object to store with: name for sort, obj for do setAttribute.

Comment: yes the solution is to create an array of object, instead of an array of string. Thanks for your guidance.